# Getting "heap corruption detected" while calling delete[] on couple of arrays in my class - C++

Tags: c++, arrays, delete-operator

I have the following code, where I am allocating memory for three int* in the constructor of the class. And deleting it later, in the destructor of the class. I am having an issue deleting two of the int*, in the destructor (I have put the comments in the code below, where I am having the issue):

```
#define CAP 3
class SetOfStacks
{
private:
    int* a1;
    int* a2;
    int* a3;
    int index = -1;
public:
    void push(int data);
    SetOfStacks()
    {
        a1 = new int[CAP];
        a2 = new int[CAP];
        a3 = new int[CAP];
    }
    ~SetOfStacks()
    {
        delete [] a1; //This works just fine
        delete [] a2; //heap corruption here
        delete [] a3; //heap corruption here
    }
};

void SetOfStacks::push(int data)
{
    if (index >= 3 * CAP)
    {
        cout << "stack overflow" << endl;
        return;
    }
    if(index>=-1 && index<=1)
    {
        index++;
        a1[index] = data;
    }
    else if (index >1  && index<=4)
    {
        index++;
        a2[index] = data;
    }
    else if (index >4 && index<=7)
    {
        index++;
        a3[index] = data;
    }
}


int main()
{
    SetOfStacks s;
    s.push(10);
    s.push(20);
    s.push(30);;
    s.push(40);
    s.push(50);
    s.push(60);
    s.push(70);
    s.push(80);
    s.push(90);

    return 0;
}
```

I debugged the code many times, but, I am not sure why I am getting HEAP CORRUPTION when I delete[] a2 and when I delete[] a3. Performing delete[] a1 works just fine. I am getting the following error on delete[] a2 and delete[] a3:

[image: heap corruption detected]

Do you know why I am getting this error, and what is causing it (I am confused why deleting a1 works fine but, deleting a2 and a3 is giving this error - though they go almost through the same logic in code)?

Comment: `if (index >4 && index<=7)` ... `a3[index] = data;` - here's your problem. You writing data outside of `a3` bounds (`a2` as well).

Comment: Do `a2[index % 3]` and `a3[index % 3]` to fix it... It will keep `index` within 0-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your arrays have a length of `CAP`, which is `3` (judging by your if-statements), but you don't relativize your indices when writing to the arrays.

```cpp
    else if (index >4 && index<=7)
    {
        index++;
        a3[index] = data;
    }
```

In these lines, you could be writing an index of up to `8` to the array.
This is why you are getting the error:

> CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.

You can fix this by using the modulo operator when writing to the indices using `index % CAP`.
For this to work properly with any `CAP`, your if-statements should also use `>= N * CAP` as boundaries.

```cpp
   else if (index >= 2 * CAP) // no upper check needed in an if-else chain
    {
        a3[index++ % CAP] = data; // you can also do index++ after
    }
```

Comment: @J.Schultke, I did all the debugging in main this time, with only a single `int* a` in main. So when I do a `int* a=new int[3]` (in main), 3 blocks of int are reserved (3 blocks of 4 bytes each). But, I can write to `a[0]`, `a[1]`, `a[2]`, but not beyond that. This is because C++ always starts at index 0. Am I correct? Why can't I write to `a[3]`, `a[4]`, `a[5]` and write to `a[0]`, `a[1]`, `a[2]` instead, since 3 blocks of memory are reserved and I am writing to 3 blocks of memory in both cases? Also, why does the problem surface later on `delete[] a`, and not when assigning to `a[3]` itself?

Comment: If you reserve 4 bytes per block, you should be able to access index `0..3`, so 4 different indices. Accessing memory beyond your first block is not allowed, because on the heap, your memory could be anywhere. If you create two arrays right after each other on the heap, they might be in completely different places. But even if you allocated them on the stack, it would be undefined behavior. It might surface later because your debugger might only do heap integrity checks when deleting memory (for performance reasons). But that's just speculation.

Comment: You could also declare a pseudo-2d array like `int *a = new int[3 * CAP];` So that the memory is continuous and you don't need to sort everything into these blocks manually.

Answer (score 1):

`index` is out of your array bounds:

```
if(index>=-1 && index<=1)
{
    index++;
    a1[index] = data; // index can be 0, 1 or 2 (fine)
}
else if (index >1  && index<=4)
{
    index++;
    a2[index] = data; // index can be 3, 4 or 5 (all out of range)
    // This fixes it:
    // a2[index - 3] = data; // index can now only be 0, 1 or 2
}
else if (index >4 && index<=7)
{
    index++;
    a3[index] = data; // index can be 6, 7 or 8 (all out of range)
    // This fixes it:
    // a3[index - 6] = data; // index can now only be 0, 1 or 2
}
```

I would also recommend making the conditions more representative of the actual indices being used so this kind of error is easier to spot:

```
if(0 <= index && index < 3) {
    a1[index++] = data;
} else if (index < 6) {
    a2[index++ - 3] = data
} else if (index < 9) {
    a3[index++ - 6] = data;
}
```